# ffmpeg batch doesnt work all of a sudden

Tags: ffmpeg, batch

I have a batch script that has always worked, but after I formated and installed Windows 11 it doesnt work anymore, tried it on another Windows 10 machine, doesnt work there either so I must be missing something.

The batch Script is:

```
@echo off
mkdir faded
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for %%f in (*.mp4) do (
    ffprobe -i "%%f" -show_entries format=duration -v quiet -of csv="p=0" >dur.txt
    set /p dur=<dur.txt
    del dur.txt
    for /f "delims=" %%g in ('powershell !dur!-1') do set fadetime=%%g
    ffmpeg -i "%%f" -filter:v "fade=t=in:st=0:d=1, fade=t=out:st=!fadetime!:d=1" -filter:a "afade=t=in:st=0:d=1, afade=t=out:st=!fadetime!:d=1" -c:v libx264 -crf 18 -preset veryslow -ab 160k "faded/%%~nf.mp4"
)
```

Anyone have a clue? When I run it, it fails:

```
> [AVFilterGraph @ 000002943a01ea40] No such filter: '714:d'
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:1
> Conversion failed!
```

Comment: The issue could be related to the regional settings. Execute `ffprobe -i "input.mp4" -show_entries format=duration -v quiet -of csv="p=0" > dur.txt`, and check the content of `dur.txt`. If the content contains a **comma** instead of a **dot**, for example: `634,53` instead of `634.53`, there is a regional settings issue. FFmpeg interprets the comma as filter separator and fails. Try [Changing decimal separator from comma to dot](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/changing-decimal-separator-from-comma-to-dot/953556fb-00d0-45ad-bd4f-6ca8afa5025a).